# Use ANTLR to write regular expressions describing the following Pascal tokens

Tags: regex, antlr, grammar

How do i use antlr to write regular expressions like those below ? Thank you.

1.For a number to be taken as "real" (or "floating point") , it must either have a
decimal point or use scientific notation. 
For example, 1.0, 1e-12, 1.0e-12, 0.000000001
are all valid reals. At least one digit must exist on either side of a decimal point.

2.Strings are made up of a sequence of characters between single quotes: ’string’. 
The
single quote itself can appear as two single quotes back to back in a string: ’isn”t’.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Looked through internet resources?

Comment: Looks like homework. Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have test tested so far for the GRAMMAR ANTLR v4 of Real Number as

```
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
INT : DIGIT+ ;
DOT: '.';
SUBREAL : ('+'|'-')?(INT)+;
REAL1: (SUBREAL ('e')? SUBREAL? ) ;
REAL2: (SUBREAL ('e')? SUBREAL? DOT SUBREAL?);
REAL3: (SUBREAL  DOT SUBREAL? ('e')? SUBREAL? );
REAL : REAL1 | REAL2 | REAL3 ;
ID : REAL;
```

new update, GOODLUCK

Comment: The REAL may generate this one: 5e.5e?

Comment: Hey mate, i have rechecked and made an updated version, thank!